# Get input with fscanf

Tags: c

I am building a program that enables the user to enter a movie and prints out the information that the user entered.

I'm using a `struct` to define the variables of a movie. The problem is that when the user enter the first to `fscanf()` **with a space**. Example: "Miami Vice" all of the other `puts()` prints after each other. The `stdin` do not work after. And I dont know why this is happening.

I've been reading about gets() and it has security issues so I should instead using fgets() or fscanf() for this. But I can't figure out what the problem is here.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
    struct movie m;

    puts("What was the title of the movie you saw?");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", m.title);
    puts("What was the relase year?");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &m.year);
    puts("How would you rate the movie? (1-10)");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &m.rate);

    printf("You saw the movie %s which was released %d and you rated it a %d", m.title, m.year, m.rate);

    return 0;
}
```

**main.h**

```
struct movie {
    char title[40];
    int rate;
    int year;
};
```

Comment: `fscanf(stdin, "%s", m.title);` --> `fscanf(stdin, " %39[^\n]%*c", m.title);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Alright, why? That looks strange to me so I need to understand what that actually does. Thanks though for the comment.

Comment: `%s` does not include the space. `%[^\n]`  will read except a newline character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%s` format instructs `scanf` to read a single word.  White space acts as a word separator, hence only `Miami` gets parsed into `m.title` and `Vice` stays in the input stream.  Subsequent calls to `scanf` with a `%d` format fail to parse an integer from the stream and return `0`, leaving `m.year`and `m.date` uninitialized.  You therefore invoke undefined behavior when printing their values with the last call to `printf`.

You can correct the problem with a different format: `%[^\n]`.  Furthermore, you should prevent `scanf` from writing beyond the end of `m.title` with a width specifier: `%39[^\n]`.  An additional  before the format will skip white space if any is present before the movie title. An additional `%*c` would read the `\n` but is not required since the subsequent `scanf("%d",...)` will skip leading white space including the `\n` left pending in the input stream.

Here is a modified version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct movie {
    char title[40];
    int rate;
    int year;
};

int main(void) {
    struct movie m;

    puts("What was the title of the movie you saw?");
    if (scanf(" %39[^\n]", m.title) != 1)
        return 1;
    puts("What was the release year?");
    if (scanf("%d", &m.year) != 1)
        return 1;
    puts("How would you rate the movie? (1-10)");
    if (scanf("%d", &m.rate) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("You saw the movie %s which was released in %d and you rated it a %d\n",
           m.title, m.year, m.rate);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "you should prevent `scanf` from **writing** beyond the end of m.title with a width specifier" ??

Comment: @user3078414: The format `%39[^\n]"` specifies a maximum of `39` characters to be copied from `stdin` to `m.title`, thus effectively prevents `scanf` from writing beyond the end of the `40` byte array.  It is the recommended way to do so.  It is too bad `*` cannot be used to specify the width of the target array, `scanf_s` fixes this shortcoming, but the error handling semantics are too complicated and this function is not always available.

Comment: This is what I understand. I've never come across the term "writing" in this context and in connection with `scanf`.

Comment: @user3078414:  `scanf` *writes* bytes to the receiving array.  What term would you use to describe this?

Comment: I've come across "read into", "copy into", which **is** _writing_, in fact. Thanks for pointing at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `fgets()` whenever reading strings as inputs. Anyways here is the code to which I modified a bit. Feel free to modify the code to your own needs.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct movie {
    char title[40];
    int rate;
    int year;
};

int main(){

   struct movie m;
   char *newline_char=NULL;

   puts("What was the title of the movie you saw?");
   fgets(m.title,40,stdin);

   //The below two lines of code are used to remove the '\n'
   //character from the input since fgets() also stores the '\n'
   //character. Replace the '\n' char with '\0' character.
   if((newline_char=strchr(m.title,'\n')) != NULL){
    *newline_char = '\0';
   }

   puts("What was the relase year?");
   fscanf(stdin, "%d", &m.year);
   puts("How would you rate the movie? (1-10)");
   fscanf(stdin, "%d", &m.rate);

   printf("You saw the movie %s which was released %d and you rated it a %d", m.title, m.year, m.rate);
   return 0;
}
```

As chux recommends, You can also use only `fgets()` and avoid `fscanf()` as shown below in the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct movie {
    char title[40];
    int rate;
    int year;
};

int main(){

    struct movie m;
    char *newline_char=NULL;
    char input[256];

    puts("What was the title of the movie you saw?");
    fgets(m.title,40,stdin);

    if((newline_char=strchr(m.title,'\n')) != NULL){
       *newline_char = '\0';
    }

    puts("What was the relase year?");
    fgets(input,256,stdin);
    sscanf(input,"%d",&m.year);
    puts("How would you rate the movie? (1-10)");
    fgets(input,256,stdin);
    sscanf(input,"%d",&m.rate);

    printf("You saw the movie %s which was released %d and you rated it a %d", m.title, m.year, m.rate);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `fgets()` is the best approach.  Yet mixing `fgets()` with `fscanf(stdin,...` will lead to problem should code loop.  Recommend to only use `fgets()`.